# Handshake Issues Tornado Server and ESP32 Client

Tags: python, websocket, arduino, tornado, esp32

I am unable to establish a websocket connection. I use an esp32 as an Client and an Tornado Webserver as Host.
I can connect to the Host with Javascript, but I can also connect the esp32 to websocket.org.
Only the connection between the esp32 and the Tornado Server doesn't work.

ESP32 Code (Arduino IDE):

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebSocketClient.h> //By Markus Sattler

const char* ssid     = "hadome";
const char* password = "12345678";

char path[] = "/ws";
char host[] = "192.168.178.29";
 
WebSocketClient webSocketClient;
WiFiClient client;
 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
 
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
 
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
 
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
 
  delay(5000);
 
  if (client.connect(host, 3333)) {
    Serial.println("Connected");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Connection failed.");
  }
 
  webSocketClient.path = path;
  webSocketClient.host = host;
  
  if (webSocketClient.handshake(client)) {
    Serial.println("Handshake successful");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Handshake failed.");
  }
 
}
 
void loop() {
  String data;
 
  if (client.connected()) {
 
    webSocketClient.sendData("Info to be echoed back");
 
    webSocketClient.getData(data);
    if (data.length() > 0) {
      Serial.print("Received data: ");
      Serial.println(data);
    }
 
  } else {
    Serial.println("Client disconnected.");
  }
 
  delay(3000);
 
}
```

Python Code Excerpt (Tornado):

```
class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True

    def open(self):
        pass

    def on_message(self, message):
        self.write_message(message)
        

    def on_close(self):
        log('[WS] Connection was closed.')

application    = tornado.web.Application([(r'/ws', WSHandler)])

# Main program logic follows:
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Tornado Server
    try:
        http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
        http_server.listen(3333)

        http_client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
        http_client.initialize(1)

        log("Tornado Server started")


        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(loop)
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
    except:
        log("Exception triggered - Tornado Server stopped.")

    finally:
        pass
```

The ESP32 Program outputs:

```
.......
WiFi connected
IP address: 
192.168.2.8
Connected
Waiting...
Handshake failed.
```

I am very confused because this javascript program works flawlessly (https://www.mischianti.org/2020/12/07/websocket-on-arduino-esp8266-and-esp32-client-1/):

```
var wsUri = "ws://192.168.178.29:3333/ws";
var output;

function init() {
    output = document.getElementById("output");
    testWebSocket();
}

function testWebSocket() {
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
    websocket.onopen = function (evt) {
       onOpen(evt)
    };
    websocket.onclose = function (evt) {
       onClose(evt)
    };
    websocket.onmessage = function (evt) {
       onMessage(evt)
    };
    websocket.onerror = function (evt) {
       onError(evt)
    };
}
```

Sincerely Hannes

PS: Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by using another library. (I use the Library of Markus Sattler)